# How to know stocked files in the server database directory?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have created a server database directory then saved some excel files using PL/SQL. Now I want to check if the file has been successfully saved ?

Comment: _" I want to check if the file has been successfully saved"_ What make you think that you can't trust the "file writing function" but that you can trust more the "file checking function"? Do you merely want to check for file's presence? You do you need to check contents too? And/or metadata?

Comment: I want to check the presence of the file.

Comment: @NG you could try to reopen the file, or use `UTL_FILE.FGETATTR`. I've posted both solutions as different answers so the community (incl. *you*) will be able to show its preference.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check the presence of the file.

Assuming you know you file's name, if you just want to test for the presence of the file, you might try to repoen it in read-only mode:

```
F1 := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('MYDIR','MYFILE','RB'); 
UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(F1);
```

If the file does not exists, you will have an exception:

```
INVALID_PATH: File location or name was invalid.
```

In addition, once the file is opened, you will be able to compare the actual content with the expected one. For example, you can check for the presence of some file signature (aka [*"magic numbers"*](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html))

Answer (score 0):

An other option (cleanest ? more preferable ?) is to use [`UTL_FILE.FGETATTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_file.htm#sthref14613)

```
UTL_FILE.FGETATTR(
   location    IN VARCHAR2, 
   filename    IN VARCHAR2, 
   fexists     OUT BOOLEAN, 
   file_length OUT NUMBER, 
   blocksize   OUT BINARY_INTEGER);
```

The third parameter indicates if the file exists or not. In addition, you will be able to get the actual file size (in bytes). Might help comparing with the expected file's size.